# SQL Server Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo siguiente error al tratar de `linkear server` a otro `SQL Server`.

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------
The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVIDOR_ENVIO_XML" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "SERVIDOR_ENVIO_XML" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.4100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476
------------------------------
BUTTONS:
&Yes
&No
------------------------------
```

Los servidores se encuentran en la misma RED.

Comment: Pueden ser dos cosas, o tu servidor no está llegando mediante la red o el servidor al que te quieres conectar no tiene habilitadas las conexiones remotas. En tal caso primero intenta hacer un ping al servidor remoto, si no te contesta el ping es problema de red, si te contesta el ping es muy probable que tengas que habilitar conexiones remotas al servidor.

Comment: desde el management studio en el servidor donde vas a crear el _servidor vinculado_, puedes conectarte a la otra base de datos (la que quieres vincular) sin problemas?

Comment: Estimados, gracias por sus comentarios, efectivamente el antivirus estaba bloqueando las conexiones TCP al servidor. Ahora ya puedo llegar y hacer las consultas remotamente.